# android-Arraylist of Object is null after doing operation in volley

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-volley

I want to access the Arrraylist after doing the volley Operation but everytime I try to access it  shows IndexOutOfBoundException.How to access the Arraylist in the onResponse method in OnCreate Method? Any Help is appreciated.Thanks!

```
 public class MovieDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView movieIdText;
    private VolleySingleton volleySingleton;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ArrayList<MovieDetails> detailsMovies = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<MovieDetails> detailsUrl = new ArrayList<>();
    public String youtubeVideoId;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_details);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String movieId = i.getExtras().getString("movieId");
        volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getsInstance();
        mRequestQueue = VolleySingleton.getmRequestQueue();
        parseMovieDetails();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),detailsMovies.get(0).getYoutube_id(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
    public void parseMovieDetails(){



        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, getUrl(100), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                MovieDetails movieDetails = new MovieDetails();
                if (response == null || response.length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Null Object", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                try {

                    JSONObject movieData = response.getJSONObject("data");
                    JSONObject movieDetailsObject = movieData.getJSONObject(Keys.EndPointMovieDetails.KEYS_MOVIE);
                    String movieTitle = movieDetailsObject.getString(Keys.EndPointMovieDetails.KEYS_TITLE_LONG);
                    long movieRating = movieDetailsObject.getInt(Keys.EndPointMovieDetails.KEYS_RATING);
                    String movieSynopsis = movieDetailsObject.getString(Keys.EndPointMovieDetails.KEYS_DESCRIPTION);
                    String moviePosterUrl = movieDetailsObject.getString(Keys.EndPointMovieDetails.KEYS_COVER);
                    String movieYoutubeId = movieDetailsObject.getString(Keys.EndPointMovieDetails.KEY_YOUTUBE_ID);
                    movieDetails.setTitle(movieTitle);
                    movieDetails.setRating(movieRating);
                    movieDetails.setSummary(movieSynopsis);
                    movieDetails.setUrlThumbnail(moviePosterUrl);
                    movieDetails.setYoutube_id(movieYoutubeId);
                    detailsMovies.add(movieDetails);

                    JSONArray torrentDownloadLinks = movieDetailsObject.getJSONArray(Keys.EndPointMovieDetails.KEYS_TORRENTS);
                    for(int i=0;i<torrentDownloadLinks.length();i++) {
                        JSONObject urlInfo = torrentDownloadLinks.getJSONObject(i);
                        String urlTorrent = urlInfo.getString("url");
                        String quality = urlInfo.getString("quality");
                        String fileSize = urlInfo.getString("size");

                        movieDetails.setDownloadLink(urlTorrent);
                        movieDetails.setQuality(quality);
                        movieDetails.setFileSize(fileSize);
                        detailsMovies.add(movieDetails);
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        mRequestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    }

    public String getUrl(int movieId){
        return UrlEndPoints.URL_MOVIE_DETAILS+
                UrlEndPoints.URl_CHAR_QUESTION+
                UrlEndPoints.URL_PARAM_ID+movieId;
    }



}
```

Comment: Hey, Roshan Please check my answer. Let me know if any problem arises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MovieDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView movieIdText;
    private VolleySingleton volleySingleton;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ArrayList<MovieDetails> detailsMovies = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<MovieDetails> detailsUrl = new ArrayList<>();
    public String youtubeVideoId;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_details);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String movieId = i.getExtras().getString("movieId");
        volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getsInstance();
        mRequestQueue = VolleySingleton.getmRequestQueue();
        parseMovieDetails();



}
    public void parseMovieDetails(){



        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, getUrl(100), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                MovieDetails movieDetails = new MovieDetails();
                if (response == null || response.length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Null Object", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                try {

                    JSONObject movieData = response.getJSONObject("data");
                    JSONObject movieDetailsObject = movieData.getJSONObject(Keys.EndPointMovieDetails.KEYS_MOVIE);
                    String movieTitle = movieDetailsObject.getString(Keys.EndPointMovieDetails.KEYS_TITLE_LONG);
                    long movieRating = movieDetailsObject.getInt(Keys.EndPointMovieDetails.KEYS_RATING);
                    String movieSynopsis = movieDetailsObject.getString(Keys.EndPointMovieDetails.KEYS_DESCRIPTION);
                    String moviePosterUrl = movieDetailsObject.getString(Keys.EndPointMovieDetails.KEYS_COVER);
                    String movieYoutubeId = movieDetailsObject.getString(Keys.EndPointMovieDetails.KEY_YOUTUBE_ID);
                    movieDetails.setTitle(movieTitle);
                    movieDetails.setRating(movieRating);
                    movieDetails.setSummary(movieSynopsis);
                    movieDetails.setUrlThumbnail(moviePosterUrl);
                    movieDetails.setYoutube_id(movieYoutubeId);
                    detailsMovies.add(movieDetails);

                    JSONArray torrentDownloadLinks = movieDetailsObject.getJSONArray(Keys.EndPointMovieDetails.KEYS_TORRENTS);
                    for(int i=0;i<torrentDownloadLinks.length();i++) {
                        JSONObject urlInfo = torrentDownloadLinks.getJSONObject(i);
                        String urlTorrent = urlInfo.getString("url");
                        String quality = urlInfo.getString("quality");
                        String fileSize = urlInfo.getString("size");

                        movieDetails.setDownloadLink(urlTorrent);
                        movieDetails.setQuality(quality);
                        movieDetails.setFileSize(fileSize);
                        detailsMovies.add(movieDetails);
                    }

                    if(detailsMovies!=null && detailsMovies.size()>0){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),detailsMovies.get(0).getYoutube_id(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        mRequestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);

    }

    public String getUrl(int movieId){
        return UrlEndPoints.URL_MOVIE_DETAILS+
                UrlEndPoints.URl_CHAR_QUESTION+
                UrlEndPoints.URL_PARAM_ID+movieId;
    }



}
```

Comment: you may not be getting your response proper. Check it.

Comment: I get the values properly when I try to access it inside the parseMovieDetails() method. But when I try to access it in onCreate method it seems that the ArrayList is null.

Comment: You are showing the Toast Just after the parseMovieDetails() method.
But it takes some time to get the Response. Thats why in the Toast you are getting null at the detailsMovies.get(0);

Do that work after the Response.

Comment: The toast was to check whether the arraylist is empty or not. ActuallyI want to access the whole ArrayList

Comment: Just comment the Toast in the OnCreateMethod. And Check. It will work fine